# Rails is putting my application into the body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

So, below is a snippet of code that I have in my application.html.erb file.

```
<doctype></doctype>
  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Test Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
```

The Issue:  For some reason rails is taking this code and adding it to the body.  (see below)  When, if i'm not mistaken, it should create the html based off of this code.  I've never run into this problem before with rails, and can't seem to find a solution.  It's not turbolinks or anything else i've been working with.  What could the issue be?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css"></style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <doctype></doctype>
    <title>Test Title</title>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. This is not my original code, i've broken it down to the bare minimum to show you what the problem i'm running into is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the doctype looks off. try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    head tags
  </head>
  <body>
    body tags
  </body>
</html>
```

with no closing tag for the doctype

Comment: I will accept your answer when it opens up.
Funny how something so silly can slip past your when your brain is on the fritz.
Apparently the generator for my slim didn't add the html after my doctype and this broke the entire thing.  Thanks!